# Unable to inject base class with @Inject annotation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations

Unable to inject the base class directly

Base abstract class

```
@Component
public abstract class A{
}

Here are my derived classes
@Named("abc")
public class B extends A{
}

@Named("cde")
public class C extends A{
}
```

I am trying to invoke A in my resource class but getting the following errors.

```
@Inject
private A a

@Component
public class Resource implements ServiceImpl{
 @Inject
    public Resource(final Client client,
            final A a) {
        Assert.notNull(client);
        Assert.notNull(a);

        this.client = client;
        this.a= a;

    }

    @Override
    public Response method1(final Request request) {
        Response response = null;
         try {
                response = (PaymentResponse) this.a.process(request);
            }
            catch (final Exception ex) {
                ex.printstackTrace();
            }


            return response;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Response method2(final Request request) {
       Response response = null;
        try {
            response =  this.a.process(request);
        }
        catch (final Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;

    }
}
```

Error during the startup of application :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'Resource' defined in file 
>   No qualifying bean of type 'a' is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: b,c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To inject correct bean you have to use `@Qualifier` annotation.

```
 @Inject @Qualifier("abc")
 private A a;
```

Right now Spring does not know what bean are you trying to inject. 'abc' or 'cde'.

Since your base class is abstract you are unable to create instance of it, therefore spring is trying to inject derieved classes. And that is why you have to decide what class needs to be injected by annotating it properly.

Comment: Is there an alternate to this way. Because im trying to extend the same base class to 30 different classes . So to avoid the same injection 30 times ? . Also is there a way we can use the qualifier at the method level ?

Comment: If it does not have to be components you could create factory component and inject it into other components. The factory could create expected object derieved from your base class. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but creating 30 classes may be sign of bad design and you may want to rethink your solution. If I helped, please accept my answer.